# Parse's Data Browser

Tags: database

Curious if anyone knows if there is a product out there that helps business folks manage values in a database without needing any coding knowledge.

I am building an app that will serve as the main client interface.  I want business folks to be able to update the database so that the app has up to date info.

Parse's data browser let's you add/update/search/filter your data and it's basically the same complexity as a spreadsheet.

1. You can add a new row
2. Update different values to the row. It helps you structure your input.  Eg dates have a calendar picker.
3. Search for a certain phrase across all columns.
4. Filter a column/ search on one column.
5. On search results, you can update the values.
6. You can't push some buttons to destroy the database/ needs to be business focused not programmer focused.  Simple/clean UI is a must.

Is there any other products out there that is like that?  Just curious to know beyond Parse if there is additional options.

Comment: For which OS? Is there a price limit? Specific features wanted?

Comment: Doesn't really matter.  Just be reasonable- no windows 3.1

Comment: For those who don't know what Parse is, could you post a URL? Which programming lannguage are you using? Is this Windows only (or cross platform, or browser-based)?

Comment: Its just parse.com   I'm open to many programming languages, and platforms.  Doesn't matter to me if i tell someone to install something or go to a website.

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on your DB's type.

For *MySQL*, there are a couple of options like **MySQL Workbench** or **Sequel Pro**:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/slideshows/top-10-mysql-gui-tools.html

For *MongoDB*, two good options are [**MongoVUE**](http://www.mongovue.com/) and [**RoboMongo**](https://robomongo.org) (which is fairly new).

And for *SQL Server*, check out [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/380/tools-for-maintaining-and-deploying-database-schemas-and-data-for-sql-server?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks but updated my question with more specifics